# My flavour of answer to Definition of Data abstraction

Tags: java, c, unix, pthreads

I am new to Java, Coming from C back ground, How can i answer the question 'Can Data Abstration be implemented in Java?' .

Here is below, what i want to answer, Please correct me, if am wrong in my thinking.

SUSv3 has introduced a datatype called pthread_t, but did not specify it's represention(like ulong or pointer to struct or etc..) and MUST be treated as opaque data.

The user who want to work on pthread_t data has to use it via functons like like pthread_equal(), in this case to check equality. But still C can not stop user to do something like 'tid == pthread_self();' at compile time despite pthread_t is opaque data.
Runtime behaviour is unknown.

Java as part of language feature, can stop user doing such thing at compile time, by introducing private/protected/package access specifier on data members within the class and use public member functions which perform the same logic on those data members.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is a use case for [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) - they are what can provide compile-time type safety.  Changing the visibility of modifiers, or introducing modifiers will not solve this, since they alone may be syntactically correct, but won't provide compile-time safety.

Take this for example:

```
public class ThreadData<T> {
    private T data;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

This class `ThreadData` is generic, and can accept any type of data I want.

Here's the example usage - comments are provided inline.

```
ThreadData<Integer> intThreadData = new ThreadData<>();
intThreadData.setData(10); // OK; this is type bound to Integer
intThreadData.setData("10"); // Not OK - will fail at compile time
```

Comment: Yes, i think we are avoiding type unsafe issues. But Before that, Do you think, We are stopping user to access the data directly by making user not bothering its representation and just rely on public functions?

Comment: Well, no.  I could do whatever I wanted to with this class with reflection; I could ignore all of your visibility and scope protections if I so desired.  So no, that doesn't help with compile-time safety.

Comment: Let us remove <T> for timebeing and consider a simple class ThreadData, i see that i can't compare saying data1==data2, Because data is private and if it was public, i could have done it.

Comment: You don't want to do it like that (and I think you're getting off-topic).  You want to override `equals` instead to check for equivalence.  If you want to compare, then you should implement `Comparable<T>` and implement an appropriate `compareTo` method.

Comment: Oh you can ignore all scope protections using reflections? i dont know what reflections is? But we can ignore scope protections? Bit weird):

Comment: here i feel, my point is. equals/compareTo method is same as pthread_equal(), because user who uses equals()/compareTo() will have to not bother on how 'T(whatever) data' is internally interpreted? similarly user who uses pthread_equal() will have to not bother on how 'pthread_t data' in internally interpreted.

Comment: In this case Data abstraction(DA) is, helping us to be away from type safety issue, may in other cases, DA will help us to be away from complexity of the logic in that implementation of feature(in our case here pthread_equal()).

Comment: We got into typesafety issues, Becasue i talked about == operator as an example, if i talk about printing the pthread_t data in C, Are we deterministic in  displaying right data using printf()? i think we should again rely on some library function which makes the user not bother how 'pthread_t data' displayed? is this also type safety issue? if it is pointer to structure, implementation will be accordingly.

Comment: one more point is if i compare tid of one process with tid of another process they may be equal in one standard and may not be equal in other standards, so how do you say they are equal by just using type safety measures? but the actual answer is not equal becasue they are from different process

Comment: So now, I feel that you've taken this a bit out of scope.  I'm not entirely sure what you're asking anymore.